# Cython on Android?

Tags: android, python, cython

Can I use Cython to compile an existing Python application for use on Android?

I have a Python 3 application with an extensive data model written in Python 3. I would like to have the data model somehow interacted with on Android, even if I have to write a thin "connecting" interface in between the two languages.

I'm thinking of using the Android NDK (C++ API) to call into the Python3 objects compiled via Cython, and rewrite the view in Kotlin/Java. I presume I'd have to embed Python into the Android device too.

Is this feasible? What would this path look like? Who (or what app) has done this?

Comment: Notably Jython does not support Python 3 as of 2018 https://github.com/jython/jython3

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "compile an existing Python application"? Turn each of your modules into an extension module, and then write your own CPython-embedding app to replace the top-level script and call into your modules with the C API? That should be doable. I remember them announcing Cython support for Android a few years ago, and a bunch of blog posts springing up with examples. If you just web search `cython android` you'll probably find lots of them.

Comment: Actually, the first ones I found are all about using Cython to build C extensions (in one case, just to use JNI) to embed in a Kivy app, which isn't quite what you're looking for… but it should be close.

Comment: Further down the list, [this tutorial series](http://joaoventura.net/blog/2014/python-android/) looks promising. Even though he's ultimately using Kivy and JNI too, and it's old enough that he didn't have a cross-compiled Python 3 for Android so he had to use 2.7, from a quick glance it looks like along the way he covers all the stuff you'd need.

Comment: It strikes me that another way to do this could be creating a data layer via flatbuffers (or pick your data serializer) and just pass the data back and forth between the two lanugages

Comment: my thoughts are consistent with you, convert .py to .c via cython The problems currently encountered are: The compiler used by cython on linux is GCC, but the latest android ndk does not support gcc, and I am thinking about using the toolchain provided by android ndk, or clang. I have seen kivy/python-for-android online. This program seems to convert python into a .so file executable on linux, but I don't know specifically about it.

Comment: I ended up with kivy